# Problems using Maps V2 and Fragments

Tags: android, google-maps, android-actionbar, fragment

I have the following situation:

- I have a simple app with 3 tabs using the android actionbar
- The first tab (not the tab but the GUI below) should contain a map

I'm not really sure how the setup with Activities, Fragments (Java) and Fragments (xml) should look like. The map examples you get from the google playservices all just use an Activity.

When working with the actionbar (tab navigation), fragments should be used. Is that right?

So i have the following components implemented which do not work propely.

```
package ch.bfh.femtho.skiguide;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public static Context appContext;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    appContext = getApplicationContext();

    // Set up the action bar to show tabs.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.

    ActionBar.Tab mapTab = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_title_map);
    ActionBar.Tab poiListeTab = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_title_poiliste);
    ActionBar.Tab meetingpointTab =    actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab_title_meetingpoint);


    mapTab.setTabListener(new TabListener<MyMapFragment>(
            this, "map", MyMapFragment.class));
    poiListeTab.setTabListener(new TabListener<PoiListeFragment>(
            this, "poiliste", PoiListeFragment.class));
    meetingpointTab.setTabListener(new TabListener<MeetingpointFragment>(
            this, "meetingpoint", MeetingpointFragment.class));

    actionBar.addTab(mapTab);
    actionBar.addTab(poiListeTab);
    actionBar.addTab(meetingpointTab);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("tab", getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex());
}

}
```

TabListener:

```
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;

public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
      * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
      * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
      * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
      */
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
```

Fragment:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapsInitializer;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.UiSettings;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MyMapFragment extends Fragment {

private MapView mMapView;
private GoogleMap mMap;
private Bundle mBundle;
private UiSettings mUiSettings;

int mCurCheckPosition = 0;

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    outState.putInt("curChoice", mCurCheckPosition);
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            // Restore last state for checked position.
        mCurCheckPosition = savedInstanceState.getInt("curChoice", 0);
    }
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.map_fragment, container, false);

    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity());
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // TODO handle this situation
    }

    mMapView = (MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mMapView.onCreate(mBundle);
    setUpMapIfNeeded(inflatedView);

    return inflatedView;
}



@Override
public void onDestroyView() {
    super.onDestroyView();
    MyMapFragment f = (MyMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    if (f != null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(f).commit();
    }
}



@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mBundle = savedInstanceState;
}

private void setUpMapIfNeeded(View inflatedView) {
    if (mMap == null) {
        mMap = ((MapView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.map)).getMap();
        if (mMap != null) {
            setUpMap();
        }
    }
}

private void setUpMap() {
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
    mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mUiSettings = mMap.getUiSettings();
    mUiSettings.setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    mMapView.onResume();
}

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    mMapView.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    mMapView.onDestroy();
    super.onDestroy();
}

}
```

Fragment (xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity" >

   <fragment
       android:id="@+id/map"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem appears when navigating to another tab and then come back to the map. Added markers disappear, camera position is lost, ...

can someone help me with this?

thanks

Comment: Hey mweb84 you solved your issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess what you should do is override the onSaveInstanceState method in the mapFragment and to save all your desired data in the savedInstantState object (including your location and markers location you created and not only the int you are saving), and in the onCreate method you should reuse all this data.

more information on saving states can be found here:

http://www.eigo.co.uk/labs/managing-state-in-an-android-activity/

Comment: Great @mweb84 : ) Good luck with your codding.